# android studio running app background running

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app which tracks the distance you ran. I want to be able to use another app ,like a music app, at the same time. I didn't find any good tutorials on how to make the app run in the background, if anybody knows any good tutorials or an easy solution to make the app run in the background I would really apreciate if you would share it with me.

Application code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StepCounter extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

// Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
// Unique tag for the error dialog fragment
private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
// Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
private boolean mResolvingError = false;

//keys



GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
TextView mLatitudeText;
TextView mLongitudeText;
TextView mcLatitudeText;
TextView mcLongitudeText;
TextView mDistanceText;
Location mLastLocation;
Location mCurrentLocation;
double d=0.0;
double lat1;
double lat2;
double lon1;
double lon2;
double dlat;
double dlon;
double raz=6371000;
double a;
double c;

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_counter);
    mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
    mcLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.llat);
    mcLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.llon);
    mDistanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dist);

    mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);
    createLocationRequest();
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!mResolvingError)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    mCurrentLocation = mLastLocation;
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
    //modified
    startLocationUpdates();
}

//pana aici merge de aici vine partea cu update

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = mCurrentLocation;
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    updateDistance();
    updateUI();
}

public void updateUI()
{
    mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
    mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    mcLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
    mcLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
}

public void updateDistance()
{
    lat1=Math.toRadians(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
    lat2=Math.toRadians(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    lon1=Math.toRadians(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    lon2=Math.toRadians(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    dlat=Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    dlon=Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    a = Math.sin(dlat/2) * Math.sin(dlat/2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dlon/2) * Math.sin(dlon/2);
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    d += raz * c;
    mDistanceText.setText(String.valueOf(d));
}
//@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}



// De aici partea cu rezolvatu problemei


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    //todo nust...
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // Show dialog using GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog()
        showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
        mResolvingError = true;
    }
}

// The rest of this code is all about building the error dialog

/* Creates a dialog for an error message */
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    // Create a fragment for the error dialog
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
    // Pass the error that should be displayed
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
}

/* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
public void onDialogDismissed() {
    mResolvingError = false;
}


/* A fragment to display an error dialog */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
        int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
        return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(
                this.getActivity(), errorCode, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ((StepCounter) getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**Service**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for your requirement .

> It's an application component that works for a long time in the
> background and does not display the user interface. If another
> application component starts the service and the user switches to
> another application, the service can continue to run in the
> background.

You can check sample demo [android-service-example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/) and [android-service-example2](http://javatechig.com/android/android-service-example)

Comment: You call service when background process start

Comment: i read about services, and from what i understood it usually a service always performs a single operation and stops itself once intended task is complete. I want the "onLocationChanged" to run in the background but for it to work i pretty much need to copy everything else and that wouldn't be a problem if i knew how to update the ui from a service but from what i read i can't communicate with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the wakefulintentservice which runs in different intervals as you set them. There are some examples out there like here:
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService

This would be recommended, because its not save that your standard service keeps running when the screen is off while jogging.

As for your comment above, you need to bind to the service from your UI and then you are able to call methods on the service. Read the documentation...